# Java permutation & combination with sublist without order

Tags: java, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Java:

I have a list of 12 'Person' objects (but let's represent them by integers to simplify calculations) of which I want to create all possible unique combinations. I found enough snippets online to help me with that (I used [this](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/java-program-doing-permutation) one so far), but here's the part I can 't figure out:

The list is divided in 4 sublists of variable length in which the order should not matter. These lengths are defined in an int array, e.g. {3,4,2,3}.

In the given example the original list could look like this:

`{ 1,2,3,  4,5,6,7,  8,9,  10,11,12 }`

Where this one would be the same so it should not be calculated:

`{ 3,2,1,  7,6,5,4,  9,8,  12,11,10 }`

I only want to calculate one because first calculating every combination and then sorting all sublists to then compare all lists would of course be very unperformant.

PS: I could'nt find a better title than this, which is why I didn't succeed at googling the problem either. Suggestions would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Isn't the total number of combinations the factorial of Person objects? 12!

Comment: @user3514900
So lets say you have the list [1, 2, 3] Do you want the answer to be [], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1,3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: Are the `Person` objects going to be 12 unique objects?

Comment: @onesixtyfourth That's *permutations*. Depending on what OP wants, they may have misused the term *combinations*.

Comment: Basically what OP has to do is make all sets ranging in size from 1 to 9 elements with combinations of numbers 1 through 12 (element order doesnt matter) and afterwards has to make every possible 4 slot combination from those sets he made previously

Comment: @onesixtyfourth that's the total number of permutations not combinations for all elements in the list more formally n P n. Actually if you apply combinations in that strict sense n C n, you would get only 1 because the order in combinations doesn't matter. here of course n refers to the number of elements

Comment: @Thresh: no, the resulting combinations should all have a length of 12 (the length of the original list)

Comment: @christopher: I'm not sure I understand the difference correctly, I'm going to look that up right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time on it and wrote some code using a library for combinations https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/#3._Simple_combinations

It prints out the combinations you need. I hope it helps.

```
public class Test {

    static List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
    static int[] groups = new int[] { 3, 4, 2, 3 };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        print("", 0, list);
    }

    private static void print(String previousVector, int groupIndex, List<Integer> aList) {
        if (groupIndex == groups.length) { // last group
            System.out.println(previousVector);
            return;
        }

        ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> vector = Factory.createVector(aList.toArray(new Integer[0]));
        Generator<Integer> generator = Factory.createSimpleCombinationGenerator(vector, groups[groupIndex]);

        for (ICombinatoricsVector<Integer> combination : generator) {
            String vectorString = previousVector + combination.getVector().toString();
            List<Integer> copy = new LinkedList<>(aList);
            copy.removeAll(combination.getVector());
            print(vectorString, groupIndex + 1, copy); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like these are indeed the correct combinations! I'm gonna need some time to figure out the code though, I'm not that experienced as you may have noticed.

Thanks a lot!